# Getting the Folder Path via the Browser using Internet Explorer

Tags: java, php, visual-studio, activex

I would like to create a folder selector for my application which will only run on Internet Explorer Browsers (IE6+).

I would like to get the full folder path a user wishes to use via a HTML browse button or similar and then pass this to my server side application which is written in PHP! This can not be done via JavaScript for security reasons so I am looking for any other alternative that will work.

I had implemented a solution using a Java Applet but this did not work out as it didn't work on IE6, plus the browser security is locked down where I am deploying this app, meaning I am unlikely to get away with an applet.

The current solution is getting the user to paste in the folder location into a textfiel, this isn't acceptable any more.

Any implementation advice welcome!

Thanks all

Comment: Are you looking for a file path on the server, the users local machine, or some other "theortical" file location?

Comment: Don't think this is a java question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is IE only you can create a simple ActiveX Control with only one method:

```
 HRESULT BrowseForFolder([out] BSTR folderName);
```

ATL Wizard will give you major portion of code.

But I would consider using **flash** for this:

1. It is more widely used then Java (I
   think so).
2. ActiveX is strongly depends on
   browser's security options and more annoying to install.
3. Your task is rather small, so it can
   be implemented without deep skills, if you not familiar with flash

Comment: Will Flash be able to give you the full path and directory structure??

Comment: I'm not a flash coder, this is just guessing. But if flash can it, it would be the best way. Anyway you can always do it with ActiveX.